# Rails jquery raty show username above its stars rate

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, raty

I'm using the jquery raty gem and I want to add the rating for each user below their username. This is what I have in the products.show html.erb:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="ratings">
    <h1> Ratings </h1>
    <% @product.ratings.each do |rating| %>
    <em> User: </em><%= User.find(rating.user_id.to_i).username.capitalize  %>
    <% end %>
    <%= render @product.ratings %>
     
     
    
    <div>
```

```html
<!-- What I see is the following: -->

Username1: Username2:
(stars rating1)
(stars rating2)

<!-- And I want this: -->

Username1: 
(stars rating1)
Username2:
(stars rating2)
```

I've tried to close the loop by placing the end below the render @product.ratings but by doing so I get all the ratings shown twice.

Answer (score 0):

I did it, using the each with index. So the code is:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="ratings">
    <h1> Ratings </h1>
    <% @product.ratings.each.with_index  do |rating, index| %>
    <em> User: </em><%= User.find(rating.user_id.to_i).username.capitalize  %>
    <%= render @product.ratings[index] %>
    <% end %>
     
    <div>
```